# Unable to build image for module on ARM64 on azure for iotedge pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-iot-edge

I am able to successfully build and deploy image for my module on amd64 architecture. However the build fails for arm64 architecture using defaultPlatform: arm64v8 in yaml file.

It fails with the warning

```
---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
```

I am assuming the build happens on an amd device and therefore fails to build. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested

Based on the error message, this issue is related to the **Docker Version 20.10.x**.

You could run the command and check the docker info: `docker info`.

Please refer to this ticket about [[v20.10] Platform architecture detection is broken](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1170#issuecomment-750371249).

This is a known issue in Docker Version 20.10.x.

You can try the following workarounds：

1. Roll back docker to 19.x version
2. Add `--platform=linux/arm64/v8` to your Docker build argument.

Many users have encountered similar issue in Docker Version 20.10, you can follow up the ticket above to check for updates.